# Pinch to zoom in microsoft office

Tags: mac, zoom, microsoft-office-2011

Does anyone know how to use the pinch-to-zoom gesture in Office 2011 for Mac? It works in most programs but not in Office.

Comment: Do you mean Office 2011? AFAIK there's no Office 2010 for Macs. Or perhaps you have Windows installed in a VM or via Boot Camp?